# Problemas con librería bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

El siguiente código es de un menú, en el cual al hacer clic en los botones no me dirige a la página correspondiente.

```
<div class="container">
            <!-- Static navbar -->
            <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="images/templatemo_logo.png" alt="Urbanic Template" title="Urbanic Template" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="templatemo-nav-bar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-top: 40px;">
                            <li><a href="index.php">INICIO</a></li>
                            <li><a href="new_report-1.php">NUEVO REPORTE</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">SEGUIMIENTO</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">DONAR</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" target="_parent">BLOG</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
            </div><!--/.navbar -->
        </div> <!-- /container -->
```

Si quito el `navbar-nav` de la clase de la etiqueta de lista desordenada los botones funcionan pero estos salen en vertical, y yo los necesito en horizontal.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no te dirige a la página correspondiente? Revisa tus etiquetas `a` porque solo tienes una que dirige a un *index.php* y el resto simplemente tiene un *#*

Comment: he estado haciendo pruebas, las que tienen enlace son la primera y la segunda (index.php y new_report-1.php), pero en ninguno de los casos me redirecciona

Comment: Intenta agregando un slash ( */* ) adelante de cada uno: ejm */index.php*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL codigo funciona correctamente solo con boostrap, lo probe en fiddle y anda de maravillas el menu para móviles. Hay 2 opciones posibles a tu problema:

1. hay código css (fuera de bootstrap) que esta aplicándose y eso hace fallar la navegación del menu
2. lo mas probable es que no pusiste los links en el atributo href de cada elemento , la mayoria estan asi: href="#" lo que genera que al clickearlos no haya ninguna redirección